# Flexible select query

Tags: sql

I know that comparison operators don't work with `null` values in SQL so for that we use `isnull`, Now I have a situation with a table like this,

```
ID      Name        Order
3   KnowledgeBase1  NULL
4   KnowledgeBase2  NULL
5   KnowledgeBase3  NULL
6   KnowledgeBase4  NULL
7   Child of first  1
```

Now here you can see that `Order` can be `null` or any numeric value,

Now here's the select query

```
declare @order int = null

select 
        ID,
        Name,
        Order
from tbl
where Order = @order
```

this query is good when `@order` has any `numerals` but when it has `null` it doesn't work of course because where clause should be `Order is null` for that case,

So question is that is there any way to do this without using `exec() with a string of query` or a conditional statement in my query ??

Comment: Using a variable named @order and a field named Order makes the code unclear, and could lead to errors/problems if you forget the "@". ORDER is a reserved SQL word.

Comment: I just trimmed the code to post it here, its not like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare `@order` to `NULL` in the where clause, and if it is, use `order IS NULL` and `OR` that together with your existing condition that works if it has a value:

```
select 
        ID,
        Name,
        Order
from tbl
where 
  Order = @order
  OR (@order IS NULL AND order IS NULL)
```

You have not specified your RDBMS, but a quick test shows this working with MySQL...

Answer (score 0):

If you use isnull with your column name it's work

> declare @order int = ''
>
> select ID, Name,  Order
> from tbl where isnull(Order,'') = @order